How can I define an Area of Interest a certain distance from a set of coordinates on the Web Soil Survey website?
I'm trying to help automate a sequence of actions that involves downloading soil data for a specific area of interest at https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/App/WebSoilSurvey.aspx.  The tool allows entering latitude & longitude coordinates, but the only noticeable way to create the AOI based on those coords is to manually click-and-drag the box.  That can be automated, but preferably I would like to offset the boundaries by specifying a perimeter a certain distance away from the coords.


The Web Soil Survey - Home is designed to be a "simple yet powerful way to access and use soil data."  Although 'powerful' is arguable, it is definitely simple and meant to be used through simple GUI tools.  If you want to automate access to soils data, you should be looking at other offerings like Soil Data Access - Home
